# Polars: Specify dtypes for all columns at once in read_csv

Tags: python, python-polars

In [Polars](https://www.pola.rs/), how can one specify a single dtype for all columns in `read_csv`?

According to the [docs](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.read_csv.html#polars.read_csv), the `dtypes` argument to `read_csv` can take either a mapping (dict) in the form of `{'column_name': dtype}`, or a list of dtypes, one for each column.
However, it is not clear how to specify "I want all columns to be a single dtype".

If you wanted all columns to be Utf-8 for example and you knew the total number of columns, you could do:

```py
pl.read_csv('sample.csv', dtypes=[pl.Utf8]*number_of_columns)
```

However, this doesn't work if you don't know the total number of columns.
In Pandas, you could do something like:

```py
pd.read_csv('sample.csv', dtype=str)
```

But this doesn't work in Polars.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Reading all data in a csv to any other type than `pl.Utf8` likely fails with a lot of `null` values. We can use expressions to declare how we want to deal with those null values.

If you read a csv with `infer_schema_length=0`, polars does not know the schema and will read all columns as `pl.Utf8` as that is a super type of all polars types.

When read as `Utf8` we can use expressions to cast all columns.

```py
(pl.read_csv("test.csv", infer_schema_length=0)
   .with_columns(pl.all().cast(pl.Int32, strict=False))
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to read all columns as `str` (`pl.Utf8` in polars) set `infer_schema_length=0` as polars uses string as default type when reading csvs:

```py
pl.read_csv('sample.csv', infer_schema_length=0)
```

This is the TLDR of [ritchie46's more detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71108347/7483211). I broke it out into a separate answer as his code snippet solves the general case for *any* datatype and not the special but common case of reading all as strings.